# In "Dann nahm er seinen Schal ab und steckte ihn sich unter den Arm", what is "ihn" here?

Tags: grammar-identification

This is a statement in a fairy tale "Der Wind und Die Sonne":

> Dann nahm er seinen Schal ab und steckte *ihn* sich unter den Arm.

What does the word *ihn* here refer to? Is it *seinen Schal* or *er*? I know the meaning

> Then he took off his scarf and put it under his arm

but I'm confused on how to interpret the grammar here.

Comment: If "ihn" referred to "er", the sentence would be pretty senseless, wouldn't it? How can one put himself under oneself's arm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As fanlim wrote, ihn refers to den Schal.

In English, we would say that the man put "it" under his arm, but in German, you need to use "ihn" (him) because der Schal is masculine. English does not generally give "genders" to inanimate objects but German does.

Comment: I think, in English ships and countries can be feminine :)

Comment: @CarstenS: Countries and ships are "animate" if you consider the people in/on them.

Comment: Ah, Schal is masculin, so es is not permitted which is neutral but ihn is correct!. This more cleary answers my question so I switched my selected answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

ihn = seinen Schal

> ... und steckte sich seinen Schal unter den Arm.

Comment: so `ihn` can refer to non-person. I though only `es` can refer to it in dative case.

Comment: Indeed, you use *er, sie, es* for any substantive without regard of what it refers to. *"Der Tisch steht schief." - "Stelle **ihn** halt gerade."*

Comment: In the sentence above, *ihn* is accusative and *sich* is dative: Jemandem (Dat.) etwas (Akk.) stecken.

Comment: @RHa Oh, I didn't notice it. It's the peculiar German way of speaking I found many times. Thanks.